# Prove $\int_0^a \sqrt{1+\cos^2 t}dt > \sqrt{a^2 + \sin^2 a}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, inequality

Prove following inequality
$$\int_0^a \sqrt{1+\cos^2 t}dt > \sqrt{a^2 + \sin^2 a}.$$
I have tried to compute first integral, but that is not possible, can someone give me hint for this problem?

Comment: What values of $a$ are permitted?

Comment: @311411 nothing is said, real I guess

Comment: @311411 I think we should have $a > 0$. Otherwise the inequality is trivially incorrect, because the LHS is negative whereas the RHS is positive, or, if $a=0$, we get a contradiction $0 > 0$.